# CI - Help Inserting Multiple Select Form with each having Multiple Selected Options

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert a list of players into multiple columns on the same row of a table. These players are grouped by positions, so they have their own Select Form that I wish to retrieve and insert into a single SQL (and I have also used javascript to limit the number of options selected.

```
Table: contests_rosters
id, player1, player2, player3, player4

player1 and player2 will be from select name "forwards[]"
player3 and player4 will be from select name "defenders[]"
```

The problem is when I call the post in the controller, I don't know how to manipulate the array so that I can do one insert instead of multiple inserts.

Could you please help me? -- Additionally if you could show me what the return of the post would be and explain the manipulation steps so that I can understand, that would be greatly appreciated.

**VIEW** - The Options are retrieved by ajax

```
Select Forward
<br/><br/>
<fieldset>
    <select name="search_forward" id="players_forwards" multiple size="25" style="width:500px">
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add_forward">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove_forward">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="forwards[]" id="players_forwards_selected" multiple size="2" style="width:500px">
    </select>

</fieldset>
<br /><br />

Select Defender
<br/><br/>
<fieldset>
    <select name="search_defender" id="players_defenders" multiple size="25" style="width:500px">
    </select>

    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add_defender">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove_defender">&laquo; Remove</a>

    <select name="defenders[]" id="players_defenders_selected" multiple size="3" style="width:500px">
    </select>

</fieldset>
<br /><br />
```

**Controller**

```
$data1 = $this->input->post('forwards');
$data2 = $this->input->post('defenders');

.....manipulation, then insert into table
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I managed to find the following solution. Not sure if it's the cleanest solution, but it works. Would be happy to hear your thoughts.

**Controller**

```
$forwards_post = $this->input->post('forwards');
$defenders_post = $this->input->post('defenders');

$forwards = array(
            'player1'       =>      $forwards_post[0],
            'player2'       =>      $forwards_post[1]
        );

$defenders = array(
            'player3'       =>      $defenders_post[0],
            'player4'       =>      $defenders_post[1]
        );

$data_entry = array_merge($forwards, $defenders);
```

The array is now ready for a single insert in the model

```
$this->input('contests_rosters', $data_entry);
```

Voila.